# MySQL order by ASC and DESC in same column

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, group-by

In MySQL is there a way to sort a column DESC for the purpose of GROUP BY but then sort that same column again ASC for the actual output? If not, then how would you recommend I re-sort them in PHP when I'm handling the results?

Comment: `GROUP BY` does not care about order.  Post your sample data and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` doesn't care about your order, it's running over the whole dataset anyway.

Comment: After playing with the query some more I realized you were right, GROUP BY just takes the first item in the list regardless of how I sort it. I was able accomplish what I wanted by selecting the MAX of the column for grouping purposes, and then I sorted it according to how I wanted the output.